# Code is bypassing await and not stoppping for api to complete

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

In reference to my previous question,I made the necessary changes but still my code was giving blank data.So ,I created a poc but this is having some  issue(blank data as output).
I can see json output on browsing 'http://localhost:50193/api/people'

On Debugging,I found below information.

**Error in POC;**
Status=Waiting or activation.
Method="null"
Result-Not yet Computed.

Also,program is exiting  on `HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/people");` so I can not debug further.

Person.cs

```
using System;

namespace CoreTaskApp
{    
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
        }
    }
}
```

PersonRepository.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace CoreTaskApp
{
    public class PersonRepository
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        public PersonRepository()
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:50193/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }

        public async Task<List<Person>> GetAsync()
        {
            await Task.Delay(3000);

            //cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/people");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(stringResult);
            }
            return new List<Person>();
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CoreTaskApp
{
    class Program
    {
       // private static CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            var repository = new PersonRepository();
            Task<List<Person>> peopleTask = repository.GetAsync();

            peopleTask.ContinueWith(task =>
                {
                    List<Person> people = task.Result;
                    foreach(var person in people)
                        Console.WriteLine(person.ToString());
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                },
                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);



        }


    }
}
```

======================================================================
Updated:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var repository = new PersonRepository();
            Task<List<Person>> peopleTask = repository.GetAsync();
            Task<List<Person>> peopleTask1 = repository.GetAsync();
            List<Person> people = peopleTask.Result;  // or 'await' in an async Main(),  C# 7.1
            List<Person> people1 = peopleTask1.Result;  // or 'await' in an async Main(),  C# 7.1

            //Add both model to create a single
            foreach (var person in people)
                Console.WriteLine(person.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: A Console app is not the best place to test async methods. Put a ReadLine() in the end of Main(), give the task time to complete.

Comment: I tried readline but it was also not returning anything

Comment: also,I believe I have added await so it should handle the time needed.Appologies I my understanding is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your Main with

```
var repository = new PersonRepository();
Task<List<Person>> peopleTask = repository.GetAsync();
List<Person> people = task.Result;  // or 'await' in an async Main(),  C# 7.1
foreach(var person in people)
   Console.WriteLine(person.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

And maybe wrap it in a try/catch.
The whole ContinueWith is of no use here.

======

Edit, for multiple tasks. 
As I said a ConsoleApp is not great so fix that first. Makes the rest more suitable for other types of programs:

```
static void Main()
{
   MainAsync().Wait();  // add some error handling
}

// option 1, async and sequential
static Task MainAsync()
{
    var repository = new PersonRepository();
    List<Person> people1 = await repository.GetAsync();
    List<Person> people2 = await repository.GetAsync();
    // use the results
}

// option 2, parallel
static Task MainAsync()
{
    var repository = new PersonRepository();

   Task<List<Person>> peopleTask1 = repository.GetAsync();
   Task<List<Person>> peopleTask2 = repository.GetAsync();
   await Task.WaitAll(peopleTask1 , peopleTask2);

   List<Person> people1 = peopleTask1.Result;  // should be completed now
   List<Person> people2 = peopleTask2.Result;  

   // use the results

}
```

Option 2 is better for a small number of CPU intensive tasks. For calling 2 APIs at the same time probaly better too, depending on network.

Option 1 is essential when Tasks depends on each other.

Comment: thanks A lot Sir, but can you explain a bit.What hanged as It similar to my solution why mine was not working ?Also,if I need 2 task and want to work after getting result from both the task,can I use my updated answer

Comment: For more tasks, use `WaitAll()`. Not sure what was wrong, or what was the aim, of your CobtinuWith. But just keep it simple, always works better.